# Go global variable initialisation

Tags: go

Issue on loading the configuration on file scope global variable.

The config setting and and loading config values inside main method

```
func main() {

    if err := config.LoadConfig(); err != nil {
        logrus.Info("Unable to read config : ")
        os.Exit(-1)
    }

    fmt.Println(config.GetConfig().Value) // print the correct value

    service.Test() // prints 0  

}
```

my config setting. config.go

```
var appConfig AppConfig

func LoadConfig() error {
  // loads config
  appConfig = .... 
}

func GetConfig() AppConfig {
    return appConfig
}
```

I have another service file with global variable defined inside service.go

```
   var x = config.GetConfig().Value

    func Test(){
      fmt.Println(x)
    }
```

Question:

Why my **global variable x inside service.go** is not initialized ?

Thanks

Comment: At what point are you seeing an issue with the variable not being initialized? And what do you mean by your second question?

Comment: updated the Test call. calling inside main method after the config load. Sorry. removed the second question. its kind of answer to my first question.

Comment: Can you change the `Test` function to take either the configuration or the value in question as a parameter, and not rely on the magic global?

Comment: Thanks. I plan to change to function with receivers and create struct with the value x after config loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution), the order of execution is as follows:

> Package initialization—variable initialization and the invocation of init functions—happens in a single goroutine, sequentially, one package at a time. An init function may launch other goroutines, which can run concurrently with the initialization code. However, initialization always sequences the init functions: it will not invoke the next one until the previous one has returned.
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

Meaning the order is roughly:

1. Global variables get initialized
2. `init()` functions run
3. `main()` runs

So your global initialization is happening before `main()` has a chance to load your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is being defined before your main or test methods are invoked, which means `appConfig` hasn't been initialized yet (as appConfig is initialized by a call to `LoadConfig`).

In order for x to be initialize-able in the way that you seem to want, you'd need appConfig to be initialized prior to main/test execution. Instead of calling `LoadConfig`, you'd instead want to have something like:

```
var appConfig = NewConfig()
```